# This should be a reduced residue system rather than a complete residue system, right?

Tags: number-theory, definition, totient-function, reduced-residue-system

In my lecture notes there is a lemma which states the following :

Suppose $a_1,....a_{\phi(n)}$ is a complete set of residues , coprime to $n$, if $k \in \Bbb N, s.t.(k,n)=1$, then $ka_1, ka_2, ….,ka_{\phi(n)}$ is also a complete set of residues  coprime to $n$.

I'm pretty sure that it should be a reduced residue system rather than a complete residue system though right ? seems as how the euler phi function only counts numbers relatively prime to n.

Comment: Isn't a complete system of residues coprime to $n$ the same as a reduced residue system?

Comment: @MiguelBoto ah that's where my confusion lay , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. This is definitely a reduced residue system.

Given a set $$S=\{1,2,\cdots,n\},$$ a complete residue system is a set $T=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ of $n$ integers incongruent $\pmod n$.

Conversely, a set $R=\{k \in S : (k,n)=1\}=\{b_1,\cdots,b_{\phi(n)}\}$ of incongruent elements is a reduced residue system and has $\phi(n)$ elements.